# Select multiple columns from one table based on MAX of one field in that table

Tags: sql-server

I've been searching for ages on this one and getting lots of answers which seem to answer the questions asked but maybe I'm just not 'getting' it. I can't seem to apply the answers to my particular problem.

I have a query which lists all of our learners and pulls all of their history records (of 4 types) or shows `NULL` if they don't have any:

```
select LEARNERS.Learner_ID
       , LEARNERS.Firstname
       , LEARNERS.Surname
       , HISTORY.DateStart
       , HISTORY.Notes
from LEARNERS left outer join 
     HISTORY on 
         LEARNERS.Learner_ID = HISTORY.Learner_ID 
           and 
         HISTORY.Category_ID in (479,480,481,482) 
order by LEARNERS.Learner_ID
```

This works great but I only want to see the latest history for each learner (or `NULL` if none) so, following some searching on here, I have tried to do this:

```
select LEARNERS.Learner_ID
       , LEARNERS.Firstname
       , LEARNERS.Surname
       , HISTORY.DateStart
       , HISTORY.Notes
from LEARNERS left outer join 
     (select MAX(DateStart) as LatestHistory, Learner_ID
      from HISTORY
      Where Category_ID in (479,480,481,482)
      group by Learner_ID) as LatestHistoryTable on 
         LEARNERS.Learner_ID = LatestHistoryTable.Learner_ID
```

Which works brilliantly and I only get one history per learner (their latest one). However; what I really need, is more info from the history table (e.g. `History.Notes, History.Officer, History.DateStart`).

I tried to simply add further columns into the subquery:

```
...
(select MAX(DateStart) as LatestHistory, Learner_ID, Notes, Officer
      from HISTORY
      Where Category_ID in (479,480,481,482)
      group by Learner_ID, Notes, Officer) as LatestHistoryTable
...
```

But that gave me an error about a text field in the group by clause  :o(

I decided that I would just add the `HistoryID` field and then `INNER JOIN` that to the `HISTORY` table outside of the subquery to pull the other fields that I need:

```
...
(select MAX(DateStart) as LatestHistory, Learner_ID, HistoryID
      from HISTORY
      Where Category_ID in (479,480,481,482)
      group by Learner_ID, HistoryID) as LatestHistoryTable
...
```

but all that did was to produce multiple lines per learner (similar to my original query) so now I'm stumped.

I'm sure it's a simple thing for an experienced SQL coder as it must come up loads of times but I'm still learning so I'm a bit stuck I'm afraid.

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row_number and desc as below:

```
select LEARNERS.Learner_ID
       , LEARNERS.Firstname
       , LEARNERS.Surname
       , LatestHistoryTable.DateStart
       , LatestHistoryTable.Notes
from LEARNERS left outer join 
     ( select RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Learner_id order by DateStart Desc), DateStart as LatestHistory, 
        Learner_ID, Notes, Officer  
        from HISTORY 
              Where Category_ID in (479,480,481,482)
              ) as LatestHistoryTable on 
         LEARNERS.Learner_ID = LatestHistoryTable.Learner_ID 
         AND LatestHistoryTable.RowN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Kannan - I've no idea how it works but it does!! (although I had to remove the `as LatestHistory` alias on DateStart)

Comment: Row_Number() get the descending numbers based on DateStart and i am selecting the first one which is the latest and related details...